# How to receive scrollbar mouse events for QGraphicsView

Tags: c++, qt, mouseevent

In qt widget `QGraphicsView` I want to detect mouse-press, mouse-release and mouse-move events. 
I derived a class from `QGraphicsView` and I have overridden the following functions:

- mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
- mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
- mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)

Now I can detect these mouse events almost everywhere, except for the area where are the scroll bars, which are part of `QGraphicsView`.
I want to be able to catch these events and move the scroll bar manually.

Edit:
I am trying to simulate second mouse in windows environment sending WM_LBUTTONDOWN,... events. I would like to be able to detect this events also for scroll bars in `QGraphicsView`.
Besides detecting the events I would like to know the event->x() and event->()y position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`QGraphicsView` inherits the `QAbstractScrollArea` class. Thus the scrollbar widgets can be accessed with the `QAbstractScrollArea::verticalScrollbar` and `QAbstractScrollArea::horizontalScrollbar` methods.

You don't even have to use event filters once you can access the scrollbar object as the `QScrollBar` inherits `QAbstractSlider` and thus offers the signals:

```
QAbstractSlider::sliderPressed()
QAbstractSlider::sliderReleased()
```

So you can just connect them to your slots like:

```
connect(horizontalScrollBar(), SIGNAL(sliderPressed()), this, SLOT(doSomething()));
connect(horizontalScrollBar(), SIGNAL(sliderReleased()), this, SLOT(doSomething()));
```

If you need the position of the event, you will have to use event filter though. You can install an event filter on the widget object.

Comment: Implementing your suggestion I can detect these events now. I would also like to get x and y positions for specific events to be able to move the scroll bar manually. I also want to detect the events when I manually send WM_LBUTTONDOWN,... windows messages (I am trying to simulate second mouse). This is possible for other part of QGraphicsView. I will edit the original question.

Comment: @ŽigaGolob : You need to show your effort and what you have tried so far. This is not a site where people give you ready made code.

Comment: I explained in the original question what I have tried. I am also reading the Qt docs to understand why this is not working for scroll bars, which are part of QGraphicsView widget and what is the correct way to override mouse event handlers for scroll bars. I tried your suggestion, which works to detect these events, but it does not fit me, because I want to catch these events, specifically the mousePress, mouseRelease and mouseMove event.

Comment: Try installing an event filter on the slider object.

Comment: Installing event filter did the job and answers the original question. I am still not able to detect manually sent windows WM_LBUTTONDOWN and other messages, but this is another story. Thank you.

Comment: I would like to know more about the manually sent `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` event. I could detect the actual mouse event using a Hook. Not sure if it will work for the simulated event.

Comment: I am trying to simulate mouse posting windows messages like this: PostMessage(hwnd, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, 0, (LPARAM)MAKELONG(x,y)).  Handle to window at specific location can be found using function WindowFromPhysicalPoint(). Besides messages I already mentioned you also have to post BN_CLICKED message. This approach is very limited and works for simple things, mostly in client area of the window, but its enough for my application. Using event filters I am now able to detect this messages in Qt.